# Why the import of gms and com.google.example could not be resolved?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I am trying to implement [Google Play Services support](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init) in my application on Eclipse. I've downloaded `google-play-services_lib` and linked it to my project. I've also downloaded [sample games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/) and extracted `BaseGameUtils` from there (it wasn't possible to link it to my project as library, so I've marked it with `Is Library` checkbox manually and then linked it):
[image: libraries]

But the following code fails:

```
import gms.common.api.*;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameActivity;
```

for both imports it says that it could not be resolved.

Upd. I've replaced the first import with

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.*;
```

but still couldn't resolve the second import problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I've downloaded the samples and used the BaseGameUtils lib from

```
android-samples-master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils
```

when

```
android-samples-master/eclipse_compat/libraries/BaseGameUtils
```

should be used instead.

Then, `google-play-services_lib` should be referenced to in `BaseGameUtils`.

Comment: Sheesh.  Thanks for posting this.  Wasted a lot of time on this one.

Comment: where is the eclipse_compat folder? in android-samples folder is only BasicSamples...

Comment: @clayton33, looks like they changed something in the folders structure (the doc - https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples - still says about `eclipse_compat`). Suggest to raise this question as issue on their github.

Answer (score 0):

I add to this...

go to root ./android-samples-master/

from there run

./Scripts/make_eclipse_compat

Then those projects are ready to be used with Eclipse